# AppCompat resources not available in one specific project

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-appcompat

I have serious problems getting the support library to work within a certain project. It is rather large already and I took it over from another developer months ago.

Problem is: I can't use any of the AppCompat resources I would need desperately. I need them because I use the support toolbar class which requires an ActionBarActivity which in turn requires the use of a theme within Theme.AppCompat.*, and those are only available within appcompat.

I did already put the following lines into my build.gradle within the app module:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0+'
```

The strange thing is, that the libraries don't show up under "External Libraries" in my "Project" view on the left. However, if I create a new project in Android Studio I have access to the support libraries right of the start. They appear under "External Libraries" and everything is fine. So the problem can't be related to my sdk installation.

My app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.app'
        multiDexEnabled = true
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':firebase_plugin')
    compile project(':geofire')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
}
```

My "External Libraries" look like that:

[image: External Libraries]

Comment: Try changing `buildToolsVerion` to 22.0.1

Comment: That seems to have helped somehow! Both of the libraries are shown under "External Libraries" now. If you post the comment as an answer I'll accept. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments: try changing `buildToolsVersion` to 22.0.1.